# Getting force close error in android in json parsing of google detect translate api

Tags: android, json, google-translate

I am using this code for detect the source language..

```
   jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONObject jsoObj2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
        JSONArray jArray = jsoObj2.getJSONArray("detections");
        JSONObject steps = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
        srcLanguage = steps.getString("language");
```

Here is the response.

```
{
 "data": {
  "detections": [
   [
    {
     "language": "fr",
     "isReliable": false,
     "confidence": 0.41935483
    }
   ]
  ]
 }
}
```

Kindly help me in order to parse this json response.

I debug that code and getting this exception.

```
org.json.JSONException: Value [{"isReliable":false,"confidence":0.41935483,"language":"fr"}] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Comment: Add your log cat error please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject jsoObj2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray jArray = jsoObj2.getJSONArray("detections");
    JSONArray jArray2 = jArray.getJSONArray(0);
    JSONObject steps = jArray2.getJSONObject(0);
    srcLanguage = steps.getString("language");
```

Because there is an array in the array.

Comment: Its not working.. Gives Error "Change type JSON Array to JSON Object at this line   JSONArray jArray2 = jArray.getJSONArray(0);"

Answer (score 0):

If above mentioned is the response you need to have a minor change

```
    jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
    JSONObject jsoObj2 = jsonObj.getJSONObject("data");
    JSONArray jArray = jsoObj2.getJSONArray("detections");
    JSONArray steps = jArray.getJSONArray(0);
    srcLanguage = jArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("language");
```

Try his please...